# How to create a button in lotus notes to see the latest email in inbox?

Tags: lotus

How can i create a button in Lotus notes 10 to see the latest email arrived with a button? I always have to sort the date tab and scroll up ( or Home button) to see the latest email. But I wanted to combine these 2 command  (Date ascending + Home button) in a single click. Is It possible to create? thank you.

Have to manually sort the date tab and scroll bar to the top to see the latest email. But wanted to combine these 2 in a single command button

Comment: Why don‘t you simply edit your preferences and always show newest mails on top... that is just three clicks and solves your problem without even one line of code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create that button: Just set the preferences to sort the Inbox descending, and Notes will automatically show your mail as you want it. Go to `More - Preferences... - Mail - Basics` and tick the option "Automatically sort date columns" and select "Most recent on top" as seen in my screenshot.

Done.

[image]

EDIT: The screenshot is from a 9.0.1 mailfile, but the setting is identical to Version 10, although the version 10 template has some additional options on that tab.